# HTML/JS application resize function bug when JS placed in separate file

Tags: javascript, html, resize

I have an HTML canvas application which resizes fine with window resizes when HTML + JS are all placed in the same file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
...
function resizer(){...}
function createGame(){
...
  resizer();
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizer);
...}
...
</script>
</head>
<body onload="createGame();">
...
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I place the JS in a separate file externalScript.js
and link to it in the HTML program with this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./externalScript.js"></script>
```

there is a bug in that if the window resizes then resizer() doesn't seemed to be called automatically. I have to reload the browser page and then it's ok.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: try to add 'defer' to the script tag?